# Tic-tac-toe React game not displaying background color as intended

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, user-interface, frontend

I want to implement a feature for the React Tic-tac-toe game as said on the new React beta docs site. The feature is to highlight the winning squares on the board if a player wins. Having struggled with writing the code and debugging to figure out the problem, I still don't get why it isn't working. Checked Kevin Wang's article on Medium on a similar problem but his approach doesn't seem to work in my case.

Just started learning React tho and wanna make sure I finish this feature and a few more and understand React well before moving on to making more projects.

Here is a link to the code on my [Codepen](https://codepen.io/gr1ntch/pen/rNrgRpJ)

The code is a little bulky but I will still show the major components here.

```
function Square({value, onSquareClick, isWinning}) {

  return (
    <button 
      className={"square " + (isWinning ? "winning-square" : null)} onClick={onSquareClick}>
        {value}
    </button>
  );
}

function Board({xIsNext, squares, onPlay, winningSquares}) {

  function handleClick(i) {
    if (squares[i] || calculateWinner(squares)) {
      return;
    }

    const nextSquares = squares.slice();

    if (xIsNext) {
      nextSquares[i] = "X";
    }

    else {
      nextSquares[i] = "O";
    }

    onPlay(nextSquares);
  }

  var winner = calculateWinner(squares);
  let status;
  let winnerName = winner;

  if (winner) {
    status = " is the winner! " + "at line " + winner.line;
    console.log(winner.line);
  }

  else {
    status = "Next Player - " + (xIsNext ? "X" : "O");
  }
 
  // A dirty trick to do make the Board component render squares in less lines of code.
  // Originally supposed to be 
  const row = [
    [0, 1, 2],
    [3, 4, 5],
    [6, 7, 8]
  ];

  return (
    <>
     <div className="status">
        <span className="winner-name">{winnerName}</span>
        <span className="status-desc">{status}</span>
      </div>

      <div className="board-row"> 
        {row[0].map((index) => <Square value={squares[index]} onSquareClick={() => handleClick(index)} key={index}  isWinning={winningSquares.includes(index)} />)}
      </div>

      <div className="board-row">
        {row[1].map((index) => <Square value={squares[index]} onSquareClick={() => handleClick(index)} key={index}isWinning={winningSquares.includes(index)} />)} 
      </div>

      <div className="board-row">
        {row[2].map((index) => <Square value={squares[index]} onSquareClick={() => handleClick(index)} key={index} isWinning={winningSquares.includes(index)} />)} 
      </div>

      {/*
      
      Changed code below to make it more efficient, cleaner and not hardcoded according to the instruction on the React Framework docs page.
      
      <div className="board-row">
        <Square value={squares[0]} onSquareClick={() => handleClick(0)} />
        <Square value={squares[1]} onSquareClick={() => handleClick(1)} />
        <Square value={squares[2]} onSquareClick={() => handleClick(2)} />
        
      </div>

      <div className="board-row">
        <Square value={squares[3]} onSquareClick={() => handleClick(3)} />
        <Square value={squares[4]} onSquareClick={() => handleClick(4)} />
        <Square value={squares[5]} onSquareClick={() => handleClick(5)} />
      </div>

      <div className="board-row">
        <Square value={squares[6]} onSquareClick={() => handleClick(6)} />
        <Square value={squares[7]} onSquareClick={() => handleClick(7)} />
        <Square value={squares[8]} onSquareClick={() => handleClick(8)} /> 
      </div> */}
    </>
  ); 
}

// Main logic of the game.
// Stores state in the history and also renders the Board component.

export default function Game() {
  const [history, setHistory] = useState([Array(9).fill(null)]);
  const [currentMove, setCurrentMove] = useState(0);
  const xIsNext = currentMove % 2 === 0;
  const currentSquares = history[currentMove];

  function handlePlay(nextSquares) {
    const nextHistory = [...history.slice(0, currentMove + 1), nextSquares];
    setHistory(nextHistory);
    setCurrentMove(nextHistory.length - 1);
  }

  // function jumpTo(nextMove) {
    // setCurrentMove(nextMove);
  // }

  const moves = history.map((squares, move) => {

    let description;
    
    if (move > 0) {
      description = "Move #" + move;
    }

    else {
      description = "You've made no moves.";
    }
    
    return (
      <li key={move}>
        {description}
      </li>
    )
  });


  // Sets the state of the toggle ascending or descending mode of the game moves.
  const [toggleUp, setToggleUp] = useState(true);


  // Function tracks the click and updates state accordingly.

  function changeGameMoves() {

    if (toggleUp) {
      setToggleUp(true);
    }

    setToggleUp(!toggleUp);
  } 

  return (
    <>
      <div className="game">
        <div className="game-board">
          <Board xIsNext={xIsNext} squares={currentSquares} onPlay={handlePlay} winningSquares={winner ? winner.line : []}/>
        </div>

        <div className="game-info">
          <button className="toggle-btn" onClick={changeGameMoves}>
            Toggle Game Moves
          </button>

          <h2>Game Moves</h2>
          <ul id="game-moves">
            {toggleUp ? moves.reverse() : moves}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

function calculateWinner(squares) {

  // These are lines checking for whether the player has played on the indicated lines signifying a win.

  const lines = [
    [0, 1, 2],
    [3, 4, 5],
    [6, 7, 8],
    [0, 3, 6],
    [1, 4, 7],
    [2, 5, 8],
    [0, 4, 8],
    [2, 4, 6]
  ];

  // Assigns the values of each line array to a, b and c respectively;
  // i.e. for line 1 which is index 0 in the lines array, 
  // a = 0, b = 1, c = 2
  // After looping, it checks if the value of a, b and c are the same and returns the value of variable a and the line which made the win.

  for (let i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    var [a, b, c] = lines[i];
    if (squares[a] && squares[a] === squares[b] && squares[a] === squares[c]) {

      return {
        player: squares[a],
        line: [a, b, c],
      };
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

I tried writing a custom solution but on not getting the expected result, I checked online and found an [article](https://medium.com/@thekevinwang/react-%EF%B8%8F-tic-tac-toe-%EF%B8%8F%E2%83%A3-extras-88e68f025772) detailing how to solve the challenges but the article was based on old React way of components which uses classes. Read through the code to understand and tried to apply the same procedure to my own code but eventually met a roadblock.

The code was supposed to change the background color of the three squares which made the win in the game.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you face is your `calculateWinner` function returns `null` or a JSON in form of `{ player: "O", line: [0, 3, 4] }` you need to handle null case using the [optional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) (`?.`).

Raplacing:

```
winner.line.includes(index)
```

with:

```
winner?.line?.includes(index)
```

every place solves the issue.

Check the working Demo:

[image: Edit cranky-curie-uosdhq]

Comment: Thanks so much. Will try out the fix.

Comment: Okay. Will do so.