# React Tic-tac-toe game fails to display columns and rows of each clicked square

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, frontend, tic-tac-toe

I have some React code which is a Tic-tac-toe game and I want to add a feature to display the location of each clicked square of the game board as columns and rows. Been met with a deadend since.

The idea I tried was getting the index of the clicked square and using that to consult a `locations` array I hardcoded and then outputting the result but this didn't work. I am using a `for` loop in the `handlePlay` function (defined in the `Board` component) to iterate 9 times and check the index of each clicked square. This (I thought) would help me get the position if I use the value returned from the `indexOf` method to access the `locations` array.

The full code is on [Codepen](https://codepen.io/gr1ntch/pen/rNrgRpJ).

Code is also shown below, although, it is bulky.

```
// Each square is formed in a Square component
function Square({value, onSquareClick, isWinning}) {

  return (
    <button 
      className={"square " + (isWinning ? "winning-square" : null)} onClick={onSquareClick}>
        {value}
    </button>
  );
}

// Board component which renders the squares
function Board({xIsNext, squares, onPlay, winningSquares}) {

  let nextSquares = squares.slice();

  function handleClick(i) {
    if (squares[i] || calculateWinner(squares)) {
      return;
    }

    if (xIsNext) {
      nextSquares[i] = "X";
    }

    else {
      nextSquares[i] = "O";
    }

    onPlay(nextSquares);

  }
 
  // A dirty trick to do make the Board component render squares in less lines of code.
  // Originally supposed to be two for loops but I cheated.

  let winner = calculateWinner(squares);
  let status;
  let winnerName = winner;

  if (winner) {
    status = " is the winner at line " + JSON.stringify(winner?.line) + "!";
  }
  
  else if (!squares.includes(null)) {
    status = "It is a draw";
  }

  else {
    status = "Next Player - " + (xIsNext ? "X" : "O");
  }

  
  return (
    <>
      <div className="status">
        <span className="winner-name">{winnerName?.player}</span>
        <span className="status-desc">{status}</span>
      </div>

      <div className="board-row"> 
        {row[0].map((index) => <Square value={squares[index]} onSquareClick={() => handleClick(index)} key={index}  isWinning={winner?.line?.includes(index)} />)}
      </div>

      <div className="board-row">
        {row[1].map((index) => <Square value={squares[index]} onSquareClick={() => handleClick(index)} key={index}isWinning={winner?.line?.includes(index)} />)} 
      </div>

      <div className="board-row">
        {row[2].map((index) => <Square value={squares[index]} onSquareClick={() => handleClick(index)} key={index} isWinning={winner?.line?.includes(index)} />)} 
      </div>

      {/*
      
      Changed code below to make it more efficient, cleaner and not hardcoded according to the instruction on the React Framework docs page.
      
      <div className="board-row">
        <Square value={squares[0]} onSquareClick={() => handleClick(0)} />
        <Square value={squares[1]} onSquareClick={() => handleClick(1)} />
        <Square value={squares[2]} onSquareClick={() => handleClick(2)} />
        
      </div>

      <div className="board-row">
        <Square value={squares[3]} onSquareClick={() => handleClick(3)} />
        <Square value={squares[4]} onSquareClick={() => handleClick(4)} />
        <Square value={squares[5]} onSquareClick={() => handleClick(5)} />
      </div>

      <div className="board-row">
        <Square value={squares[6]} onSquareClick={() => handleClick(6)} />
        <Square value={squares[7]} onSquareClick={() => handleClick(7)} />
        <Square value={squares[8]} onSquareClick={() => handleClick(8)} /> 
      </div> */}
    </>
  ); 
}

// Main logic of the game.
// Stores state in the history and also renders the Board component.

export default function Game() {
  const [history, setHistory] = useState([Array(9).fill(null)]);
  const [currentMove, setCurrentMove] = useState(0);
  const xIsNext = currentMove % 2 === 0;
  const currentSquares = history[currentMove];

  function handlePlay(nextSquares) {
    const nextHistory = [...history.slice(0, currentMove + 1), nextSquares];
    setHistory(nextHistory);
    setCurrentMove(nextHistory.length - 1);

    // What I wanna get here is to get the value of the index of each clicked square and then use that to find the position in the locations array but it didn't work out.

    for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    // var location = row[i].map((index) => locations[index]);
      var squareIndex = history.indexOf(nextSquares[i]);
      console.log("This is the current square index " + squareIndex);
    // console.log(location);
    }
  
  }

  // console.log(currentSquares);
  // function jumpTo(nextMove) {
    // setCurrentMove(nextMove);
  // }
  
  /* setHistory({
    history: history.concat(
      [
        {
          squares: currentSquares, 
          location: 
            [
              row[0].map((index) => locations[index]),
              row[1].map((index) => locations[index]),
              row[2].map((index) => locations[index])
            ]
        }
      ]
    )
  }); */

  /* for (let i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {
    var location = row[i].map((index) => locations[index]);
    // console.log(location);
  } */

  console.table("This is the current location " + history);

  const moves = history.map((_squares, move) => {

    for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
      // var location = locations[i];
    }

    console.log("History at move " + history[move].locations);
    // const histIndex = locations[8];

    // console.log("This is the history index " + histIndex);

    let description;
    
    if (move > 0) {
      description = "Move #" + move + " at location " + histIndex;
    }

    else {
      description = "You've made no moves.";
    }

    return (
      <li key={move}>
        {description}
      </li>
    )
  });

  // Sets the state of the toggle ascending or descending mode of the game moves.
  const [toggleUp, setToggleUp] = useState(true);

  // Function tracks the click and updates state accordingly.

  function changeGameMoves() {

    if (toggleUp) {
      setToggleUp(true);
    }

    setToggleUp(!toggleUp);
  } 

  return (
    <>
      <div className="game">
        <div className="game-board">
         
          <Board xIsNext={xIsNext} squares={currentSquares} onPlay={handlePlay} />
        </div>

        <div className="game-info">
          <button className="toggle-btn" onClick={changeGameMoves}>
            Toggle Game Moves
          </button>

          <h2>Game Moves</h2>
          <ul id="game-moves">
            {toggleUp ? moves.reverse() : moves}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

var locations = [
      [1, 1],
      [2, 1], 
      [3, 1],
      [1, 2],
      [2, 2],
      [3, 2],
      [1, 3],
      [2, 3],
      [3, 3],
  ];

const row = [
  [0, 1, 2],
  [3, 4, 5],
  [6, 7, 8]
];

function calculateWinner(squares) {

  // These are lines checking for whether the player has played on the indicated lines signifying a win.

  const lines = [
    [0, 1, 2],
    [3, 4, 5],
    [6, 7, 8],
    [0, 3, 6],
    [1, 4, 7],
    [2, 5, 8],
    [0, 4, 8],
    [2, 4, 6]
  ];

  // Assigns the values of each line array to a, b and c respectively;
  // i.e. for line 1 which is index 0 in the lines array, 
  // a = 0, b = 1, c = 2
  // After looping, it checks if the value of a, b and c are the same and returns the value of variable a and the line which made the win.

  for (let i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    var [a, b, c] = lines[i];
    if (squares[a] && squares[a] === squares[b] && squares[a] === squares[c]) {

      return {
        player: squares[a],
        line: [a, b, c],
      };
    }
  }
  return null;
}

// TODO: Find the index of the clicked square and use the value to get the location from the locations array.
```

Comment: You are asking the same question again? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75392771/tic-tac-toe-react-game-not-displaying-background-color-as-intended/75401171#75401171

Comment: It isn't the same question. The last one was on making the background color change. I'm trying to output the location of each clicked square as a row and column combo.